# Excel VBA: Overflow error from too many undestroyed objects?

Tags: oop, excel, class, vba, solver

when performing optimization tasks on a large dataset I receive an overflow runtime error 6 from time to time (generally after 1 hour or 2). The error goes away when I restart my macro from where it stopped, i.e. launch the macro again from the point where the error occured. Could an overflow error be related to some issue of having created too many objects that are not destroyed properly after use?

Here's a (simplified version) of my container class, which is used destroyed (via Set ... = nothing) and reconstructed (via Set ... = New) thousands of times.

```
'CG_data_point custom collection class
    Public data_points As Collection
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set data_points = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub AddDataPoint(mydate as date, price as double)
    Dim new_data_point As CG_data_point
    Set new_data_point = New CG_data_point
    new_data_point.EnterData mydate, price
    data_points.Add new_data_point
    Set new_data_point = Nothing 'I assume this one could also be skipped
End Sub

Public Sub RMSE(X as double) as double
...
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Dim data_point As CG_data_point
    For Each data_point In data_points  'destruct each data point individually
        Set data_point = Nothing
    Next data_point
    Set data_points = Nothing
End Sub

'Main module
dim global_container as CG_data_container

sub do_optimizations()
    Do
          set global_container= new CG_data_container
           .... do something with the data, have in call to global function RMSE_UDF as a cell formula for Solver
          set global_container= nothing
    While (...)
end sub

'worksheet function
function RMSE_UDF(X as double)
     global_container.RMSE(X)
end function
```

The container variable global_container has to be global because it must be callable from a worksheet UDF (RMSE_UDF); a worksheet formula cannot have an object as argument, as far as I know, like "=RMSE(MyContainer,...)". The minimization of Root Mean Squared Errors (RMSE) is carried out with Excel Solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is necessarily the cause of your error but it is worth fixing anyway.

Compare and contrast these two parts of your code:

From `AddDataPoint`

```
data_points.Add new_data_point
Set new_data_point = Nothing
```

Here we are adding an object referred to by the temporary variable `new_data_point` to the collection. We then set `new_data_point` to `Nothing` to remove the reference to the object that it used to refer to. Obviously the collection will still have a reference to this object

From `Class_Terminate`

```
For Each data_point In data_points  'destruct each data point individually
    Set data_point = Nothing
Next data_point
```

Here we are reading each item in turn from the collection into a temporary variable called `data_point`. We then set `data_point` to `Nothing` to remove the reference to the object that it used to refer to. (Maybe not quite so) obviously, the collection will still have a reference to this object.

To remove every object from the collection try repeatedly removing the first object in the collection until the collection is empty:

```
Do Until (data_points.Count < 1)
    data_points.Remove 1
Loop
```

Comment: this makes perfectly sense. thanks for pointing out this error to me. it's a bit confusing to thinking in terms of references and reference counters when in other languages you are used to pointers. However, if any body has still another idea why there might be this problem, I'll be happy to here about it.

Comment: i have an additional question with respect to your proposed solution: isn't the collection emptied anyway with the Set data_points = Nothing command in the destructor?

Comment: you really hit the mark, after replacing my loop in Class_Terminate with yours (involving remove) the error has not popped up again even after having the macro running for 10 hours in a row! So I deduce that, as I initially conjectured, overflow errors (i.e. runtime error 6) can very well stem from undestroyed objects.

Comment: Great - in reply to your 2nd comment: setting `data_points` to `Nothing` should have sufficed to clear all of the references. I'm not sure why we need the extra step of removing each item from the collection too but at least it's working now

Answer (score 0):

In this case, an [overflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzsytfc8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) results when you attempt an assignment that exceeds the limits of the assignment's target. Could your data set have something in it that exceeds the limit of a date or possibly a double? Those are the 2 types that I see getting passed in. Maybe there is a mismatch somewhere and a big double is getting passed in as a date. You can check for this kind of stuff with a subroutine that, for instance, checks the bounds of a date before trying to write it to the collection.

The other possibility is the size of the collection itself, since it is indexed by a long. That is a pretty big number though, you would have to exceed 2,147,483,647 records.

Comment: the collections grows to about only 2500 records (days) for every optimization run. As you can see, the collection class is destroyed every time, so it's not intended to exceed this magnitude. I'll check again that no variable hits its type boundaries, although I'm pretty sure none does not since when I relaunch the procedure from where it stopped (letting it process the same actual data again), I cannot reproduce the error. So you exclude some memory leak from undestructed objects as possible cause?